# sqlalchemy AND operator from dict

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am getting this weird behavior

```
test_dict = {'productDue' : ['foo'],'releaseDue' : ['bar']}
for attr, value in test_dict.items() :
    print attr
    and_args = [(and_(getattr(my_table,attr).in_(value)))]
```

This gives me :

```
>>> print and_(*and_args)
"my_table"."releaseDue" IN (:releaseDue_1)
```

Then when I switch the order :

```
 test_dict = {'releaseDue' : ['bar'],'productDue' : ['foo']}
for attr, value in test_dict.items() :
    print attr
    and_args = [(and_(getattr(my_table,attr).in_(value)))]
```

I get :

```
>>> print and_(*and_args)
"TDC"."releaseDue" IN (:releaseDue_1)
```

I don't get it, I want to have `"TDC"."releaseDue" IN (:releaseDue_1) AND "TDC"."productDue" IN (:productDue_1)`

Help please

Answer (score 1):

Thank you,

I've managed to do it with this :

```
and_args = [ (and_(getattr(my_table,attr).in_(value))) for attr, value in test_dict.items() ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm no sqlalchemy expert, but is this hapenning because you are overwriting and_args with each pass of the loop?

Does something like

```
test_dict = {'productDue' : ['foo'],'releaseDue' : ['bar']}
and_args = []
for attr, value in test_dict.items() :
    print attr
    and_args.append( and_(getattr(my_table,attr).in_(value) )
all = and_(*and_args)
```

do the trick?